# core data saving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I created an entity object and tried to save it to the sqllite it say saving done , without error but it not be displayed in the database any suggestion to solve that

I use the following code

```
Studies *study_NEW = (Studies *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Studies" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_NEW];

study_NEW.SudyID = study.SudyID;
error = nil;
if (![study_NEW.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
// Handle error
NSLog(@"Unresolved error study %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
abort();  // Fail
}
else{
NSLog(@"Study inserted successfuly");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by data base...? are you looking in it manually? just retrieve its value in your code.....

Comment: I use coredata to save and retrieve , while retrieve nothing return I get teh sqlite file and opened it I find the table studies doesn't contains records

Comment: Please show the code you are using to display the data.

Comment: it's a simple fetchrequest , I made sure that the table is empty

Comment: How did you prepare `managedObjectContext_NEW`? Is it a valid MOC?

Comment: managedObjectContext_NEW = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
  [managedObjectContext_NEW setPersistentStoreCoordinator: persistentStoreCoordinator_NEW]; yes it's valid , I use the same context using the same code with another table and insertion done ,I don't know why with this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Studies *study_NEW = (Studies *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Studies" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_NEW];

//study_NEW.SudyID = study.SudyID;

[study_NEW setSudyID:[study SudyID]];
```

OR

```
[study_NEW setSudyID:study.SudyID];

error = nil;
if (![study_NEW.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

// Handle error
NSLog(@"Unresolved error study %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

exit(-1);  // Fail

}

else{

NSLog(@"Study inserted successfuly");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When this code executes, the first line would cause an exception if the `NSManagedObjectContext` was invalid. So my guess is that your `NSManagedObjectContext` isn't connected to the persistant store you think it should be connected to. Check your context setup code.  Maybe the code fails to connect your persistent store to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

I thought a save sent to an `NSManagedObjectContext` with no persistent store is a `NOP`, no operation performed, which should always succeed. So I tried it with one of my projects, I commented out the attachment of a persistent store to a context, and ran the program. The program threw an exception when it tried to save. Therefore you must have a persistent store, or the save message sent to your context would cause an exception.

So what is `managedObjectContext_NEW`? Is that a property of your object? Does it have an accessor method that creates a new `NSManagedObjectContext` clobbering the old context, and overwriting the persistent store?  Each time you access that property you could be erasing any previously saved data.

This code example is fine. The problem lies elsewhere with the setup of the context.

Comment: Study inserted successfuly is appear at the log file , which mean it successed in insertion